# ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "spring_session_attributes_pk"\n Detail: Key (session_primary_id, attribute_name)

Tags: spring, postgresql, spring-boot, spring-session

Currently, I'm using:

- Spring boot 2.2.2
- Spring jdbc 2.5.0
- Spring core 2.5.0

Sometimes, I got errors when accessing my endpoints, here is the stack trace, this happen after upgrading my library from:

- spring boot 2.1.7
- spring jdbc 2.1.8
- spring core 2.1.8

Handle DataIntegrityViolationException: PreparedStatementCallback;

```
SQL [INSERT INTO SPRING_SESSION_ATTRIBUTES(SESSION_PRIMARY_ID, ATTRIBUTE_NAME, ATTRIBUTE_BYTES) SELECT PRIMARY_ID, ?, ? FROM SPRING_SESSION WHERE SESSION_ID = ?];
ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint \"spring_session_attributes_pk\"
    Detail: Key (session_primary_id, attribute_name)=(a9427ef5-92a4-4845-8769-e034c3b50b70, SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT) already exists.; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: 

ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint \"spring_session_attributes_pk\"
    Detail: Key (session_primary_id, attribute_name)=(a9427ef5-92a4-4845-8769-e034c3b50b70, SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT) already exists.
    org.springframework.dao.DuplicateKeyException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [INSERT INTO SPRING_SESSION_ATTRIBUTES(SESSION_PRIMARY_ID, ATTRIBUTE_NAME, ATTRIBUTE_BYTES) SELECT PRIMARY_ID, ?, ? FROM SPRING_SESSION WHERE SESSION_ID = ?]; 

ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint \"spring_session_attributes_pk\"
    Detail: Key (session_primary_id, attribute_name)=(a9427ef5-92a4-4845-8769-e034c3b50b70, SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT) already exists.; nested exception is org.postgresql.util.PSQLException:

ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint \"spring_session_attributes_pk\"
    Detail: Key (session_primary_id, attribute_name)=(a9427ef5-92a4-4845-8769-e034c3b50b70, SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT) already exists.
    at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLErrorCodeSQLExceptionTranslator.java:243)
```

Here is my session tables:

```
CREATE TABLE APP_SPRING_SESSION (
        PRIMARY_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
        SESSION_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
        CREATION_TIME BIGINT NOT NULL,
        LAST_ACCESS_TIME BIGINT NOT NULL,
        MAX_INACTIVE_INTERVAL INT NOT NULL,
        EXPIRY_TIME BIGINT NOT NULL,
        PRINCIPAL_NAME VARCHAR(100),
        CONSTRAINT APP_SPRING_SESSION_PK PRIMARY KEY (PRIMARY_ID)
);

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX APP_SPRING_SESSION_IX1 ON APP_SPRING_SESSION (SESSION_ID);
CREATE INDEX APP_SPRING_SESSION_IX2 ON APP_SPRING_SESSION (EXPIRY_TIME);
CREATE INDEX APP_SPRING_SESSION_IX3 ON APP_SPRING_SESSION (PRINCIPAL_NAME);

CREATE TABLE APP_SPRING_SESSION_ATTRIBUTES (
       SESSION_PRIMARY_ID CHAR(36) NOT NULL,
       ATTRIBUTE_NAME VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
       ATTRIBUTE_BYTES BYTEA NOT NULL,
       CONSTRAINT APP_SPRING_SESSION_ATTRIBUTES_PK PRIMARY KEY (SESSION_PRIMARY_ID, ATTRIBUTE_NAME),
       CONSTRAINT APP_SPRING_SESSION_ATTRIBUTES_FK FOREIGN KEY (SESSION_PRIMARY_ID) REFERENCES APP_SPRING_SESSION(PRIMARY_ID) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Does anyone know how to fix the problem?

Comment: Never mix versions of a a framework that is trouble waiting to happen. Use 2.5.x (the same x) for each module not mix and match!.

Comment: I just came across this issue too, I have Spring Session JDBC with PostgreSQL set up too. The app worked fine until Spring WebFlux was integrated for a single endpoint (downloading large data using WebClient and streaming the data buffers into the response). Will investigate further and let you know.

Answer (score -3):

These errors mean that there are already records with such keys in your database.
You can clear the database or change the keys and the Insert queries.

Comment: Please explain how this is related to spring session

Comment: @PaulA.Trzyna  This is not a spring error, but a database error.